# C# ASP.NET Core 2.0 + Azure AD authentication: auto sign out after user's inactivity for certain period

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app, which uses Azure Active Directory authentication. I need it to sign out a user, if he/she is inactive for, say, 15 minutes. How can I do that?

Comment: You want to sign them out from your app, or from Azure AD as well?

Comment: I want to sign out from the app and from Azure AD as well.

Comment: From the app, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found any other way to solve this than using JS script in the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("body").on('click keypress', function () {
        ResetThisSession();
        });
    });

    var timeInSecondsAfterSessionOut = 900; // change this to change session time out (in seconds).
    var secondTick = 0;

    function CheckPage() {
        if (window.location.pathname == "/Account/SignedOut") {                
            return;
        } else {                
            StartThisSessionTimer();
        }
    }

    function ResetThisSession() {
        secondTick = 0;
    }

    function StartThisSessionTimer() {
        secondTick++;
        if (secondTick > timeInSecondsAfterSessionOut) {
            clearTimeout(tick);
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SignOut", "Account")';
            return;
        }
        tick = setTimeout("StartThisSessionTimer()", 1000);
    }

    CheckPage();

</script>
```

Comment: Two issues:  1. It takes me to an Azure "which account would you like to sign out of" page which looks almost identical to the sign in page.  2. Pressing the browser's back button takes me back into the application - it doesn't expire the session.